# Setting permissions in flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm reading the Flask Web Development book by Miguel Grinberg and I'm confused by how he's setting the Permissions for the various tasks in the app.  Is he just setting random bit values for each of the tasks?

```
class Permission:
    FOLLOW = 0x01
    COMMENT = 0x02
    WRITE_ARTICLES = 0x04
    MODERATE_COMMENTS = 0x08
    ADMINISTER = 0x80
```

He goes on to say "each task will be assigned a bit position, and for each role the tasks that are allowed for that role will have their bits set to 1."  I'm not really sure what he means.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Represent each permission flag as an 8-bit binary integer:

```
class Permission:
    FOLLOW            = 0b00000001
    COMMENT           = 0b00000010
    WRITE_ARTICLES    = 0b00000100
    MODERATE_COMMENTS = 0b00001000
    ADMINISTER        = 0b10000000
```

Notice how for each flag, the `1` is in its own column. That way, you can bitwise OR together multiple flags to give a user any combination of permissions:

```
   0b00000001  # FOLLOW
   0b00000010  # COMMENT
|  0b00000100  # WRITE_ARTICLES
=============
   0b00000111  # FOLLOW, COMMENT, and WRITE_ARTICLES
```

To test if a user has a given permission, you bitwise AND it with a given flag:

```
   0b10000101  # ???
&  0b10000000  # ADMINISTER
=============
   0b10000000  # The result isn't 0, so the user has the ADMINISTER flag
```

It's just a space-efficient way to encode a fixed number of permissions in an integer.

Comment: Wow thats cool.  I'm not sure I follow you on the last example.  What are you trying to prove by doing a bitwise AND?  Is `0b10000101` suppose to be a type of permission or a combination of permissions?

Comment: @Brosef: It's a user's permission flag. It encodes all of that users permissions in one number.

Comment: Gotcha.  I guess i'm confused by what you're trying to accomplish by ANDING the permission flag with the ADMIN

Comment: He later goes on to assign user roles by doing the following: `'User': (Permission.FOLLOW | Permission.COMMENT | Permission.WRITE_ARTICLES)` which I understand but for the admin he only does `'Administrator': (0xff)`  Where is he getting 0xff?  I thought the Admin would just be `0b10000000` or `0x80`

Comment: @Brosef: `0xff == 0b11111111`, so the administrator has all the permissions (including the Administrator permission?).

Comment: So there's an administrator with `0xff==0b11111111` then theres `0x80 == 0b10000000` with administration access?  Whats the difference?

Comment: @Brosef: `ADMINISTRATOR` is just a flag. In your code, you could write something like `def has_permission(flag, permission):  return (flag & ADMINISTER != 0) or (flag & permission != 0)`, or you give all administrators  every possible permission and check if a user has a given permission just by looking for a specific bit. It's one way of doing things.